# Remap combination of two keys

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to remap combination of insert and ' key. I know I can use asterisk for a single key but how do I use it for combination of two?

```
*insert & '::
  SetKeyDelay -1
  Send {Blind}{lwin DownTemp}
return

*insert & '::
  SetKeyDelay -1
  Send {Blind}{lwin Up}
return
```

Answer (score 2):

this maybe give you answer:
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo

> Unlike a normal hotkey, custom combinations act as though they have the wildcard (*) modifier by default. For example, 1 & 2:: will activate even if Ctrl or Alt is held down when 1 and 2 are pressed

[image]